# Why do I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol"?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ftdi, cannot-find-symbol

I try to run the FTDI hyperterminal with the source code I downloaded from their website. This is the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.ftdi.j2xx.hyperterm"
          android:versionCode="2"
          android:versionName="1.0">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.ftdi.j2xx.hyperterm.J2xxHyperTerm"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

This line is the problem:

```
android:name="com.ftdi.j2xx.hyperterm.J2xxHyperTerm"
```

"Cannot resolve symbol"...

When I look in the folder "com.ftdi.j2xx.hyperterm", there are three classes: BuildConfig, Manifest and R. But no J2xxHyperTerm. I don't think there's a mistake in the official source code, but I don't see what I'm missing here...

Comment: Are you correctly pointing to the source code you downloaded?  In other words, have you modified your build.gradle sourceSets.main.java to include the path to this source?

Comment: It wasn't using the Gradle build system, I didn't notice that.